# check string & remove unwanted sign from the value

Tags: php, sql, string

I have a Table which looks like:

```
id   route_path
1    GPMNAC(90)>GPBGB2(180)>GPIZP1(180)>GPRJB1
2    GPMNAA-GPMNA1-GPSKM1
3    GPKSM4>>GPKSM5>DHEPZ3
4    GPKSM2>>GPISL1>GPJJR18>>GFGTR
```

I have to remove  `(90)`, `-`, `>>` this type sign and have to make them like this: `GPMNAC>GPBGB2>GPIZP1>GPRJB1`, `GPMNAA>GPMNA1>GPSKM1`, `GPKSM4>GPKSM5>DHEPZ3`, `GPKSM2>GPISL1>GPJJR18>GFGTR` respectively.

please give me the proper solution. Help me to find the answer.

Comment: Are we talking about SQL ? Please add the tag of the language you're using.

Comment: I am using PHP language for this. Is it possible to find out & remove the sign in SQL? If yes, then what is that?

Comment: I personally don't know how to use either of them, but adding the relevant tag ensures that people that do will see your question :)

Answer (score 4):

To replace `(any-number)` use regex and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace('/\(\d+\)/', '', $row['route_path']);
```

To replace `-` and `>>` use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace(['-', '>>'], '>', $row['route_path']);
```

Comment: /\(\d+\)/ -> this only replace the (90), not the whole number

Comment: but at first I have to check whether the string has unwanted sign or not. If there is, then remove it from the string. how can I check it??

Comment: @RashidCordero Yes, but `\(\d+\)` will match `(90)`

Comment: @sharvanaz Just replace, no error will be thrown if nothing to replace

Comment: only at (90), so he will loop it?

Comment: @RashidCordero What you mean? Pattern will match any integer between `()` and `preg_replace` will replace all matches

Comment: @RashidCordero that one expression will remove everything like `(90)` or `(20)` or `(200000000000)` or `(1)` etc

Comment: ahhh, i understand it now thanks. currently im learning how to use regex and strugling to have multiple matches with same pattern. I found it now that its really hard to do it so doing the preg_replace is much better thing to do, thank you so much

Comment: thank you so much @HankyPanky but this code show me a fatal error like this.. "Call to undefined function makeReplacements()" Is there any solution?

Comment: That function is also defined on that link

Comment: if ((strpos($route_path, '-') !== false) || (strpos($route_path, '>>') !== false) || (strpos($route_path, '\(\d+\)') !== false))
{
$route_path = preg_replace('/\(\d+\)/', '', $route_path);
 $route_path= str_replace(array('-', '>>'), '>', $route_path);
echo "<br>" .$route_path."</br>";
}

I am doing this in this way. but it does not replace (90) or (180) numbers. Will you please give me a solution of this @HankyPanky??

Comment: The function that you should be using is clearly defined here https://eval.in/563460 you can copy it from there. Your own version is a misinterpretation of this answer and i can't comment on that. You don't need those checks